# Proof of Grothendieck's Vanishing Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I have a question about a step in the proof of Thm. 2.7 in Hartshorne (p. 210):

[image]

Why and how the sheaf $\mathcal{F}_U :=  i_!(\mathcal{F}|_U)$ regarded as a sheaf on the closere $\bar{U}$ concretely?

Intuitively I would guess by restricting but $i_!(-)$-operation implies that  $\mathcal{F}_U$ comes from a sheafification of a sheaf on $U$, so I'm not sure if ones come back to the same sheaf on $U$ by restriction a sheafification...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $h: \overline U \hookrightarrow X$ be the closed immersion. They consider $h^{-1}\mathcal F_U$ and notice that this does not change anything, more concretely:

$\mathcal F_U$ is supported on $\overline U$, hence the canonical map $\mathcal F_U \to h_*h^{-1}\mathcal F_U$ is an isomorphism (*), thus $$H^j(X,\mathcal F_U)=H^j(X,h_*h^{-1}\mathcal F_U)=H^j(\overline U,h^{-1}\mathcal F_U).$$

Now they use induction on the number of irreducible components to deduce that the RHS is zero whenever $j > \dim X$. Note that it does not matter how exactly $\mathcal F_U$ was defined. The only important fact is that its support is contained in $\overline U$.

---

(*) Of course we can check this on the stalks. This easy because you know how to compute the stalks after $h^{-1}$ (for every map) and you also know how to compute the stalks after $h_*$ (not in general, but if $h$ is a closed immersion).

---

Summarizing, we have shown the following easy-to-memorize statement: You can compute the cohomology of a sheaf on the closure of its support.

Comment: Well, Grothendieck vanishing theorem is not only about quasi-coherent sheaves, and even if $\mathcal{F}$ was quasi-coherent, then $\mathcal{F}_U=i_!\mathcal{F}|_U$ is not quasi-coherent anymore, so I disagree with your algebraic remark $(*)$ (but only with that : in your last sentence, you don't need a quasi-coherent sheaf )

Comment: Of course, you are right, one can formulate the same answer more topologically without using schemes and quasi-coherent sheaves.

Comment: Instead of $h^*$ one should then write $h^{-1}$. I have edited the answer to make it purely topological. Thanks @Roland